# Why a constructor should be in the class scope?

Tags: c#, constructor

A *Constructor* is used to instantiate(allocate memory) for an object. Yet if I write a class like this:

```
class Sample
{
    int a=10,b=20;
}
```

In above example what is the purpose of *Constructor*? I am assigning values to  variables anyway, ts *Constructor* compulsory in every case?

Comment: You need to do more reading and less wondering why https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors

Comment: Does `class Sample
        {
            int a = 10;
            int b = a * 2;
        }` compile? If not, that is **one example** of why a constructor is helpful (since it allows you to do things that are not possible / hard without them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialization of values of different variables is critical in any application development. C# does initialize simple data-types to default values as per the language specification in the .Net framework, but for classes that are user specific, it is obvious that you would be the only one who can decide what is an ideal default value. The means of achieving this is Constructors. There is also a perception that constructors can only be used beyond initialization, which is true to some extent.

Reference :

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/vishnuprasad2005/HowuseCSharpConstructors11302005015338AM/HowuseCSharpConstructors.aspx

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/09/csharp-constructor-example-types-of-constructor-in-csharp.html